# Tier Pricing Issue - Please Help

Tags: magento-2.1, discount, tierprice

I need to apply a Tier Pricing by 10 Units. But not for unit number 11. Just by group of 10 units or 20 o 30. This is because we offer discount by closed package.
And the package contained 10 units. We don't want to discount the other units that doesn't fits in a closed package.